# No MessageBodyWriter for Single

Tags: jaxb, rx-java, rx-java2, resteasy, vert.x

I'm trying to use resteasy-rxjava2 to provide an XML document using jaxb, within a vertx application (using a non-vertx legacy library we have). But I get:

```
Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type:
org.jboss.resteasy.rxjava2.propagation.ContextPropagatorOnSingleAssemblyAction$ContextPropagatorSingle of media type:
application/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

From what I can tell, this comes down to the difference between a `MessageBodyWriter` and the `AsyncResponseProvider` that is in the resteasy-rxjava2 dependency for a `Single` (`SingleProvider`).

I have the following resteasy service definition

```
  @GET
  @Path(FdsnwsPaths.QUERY)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  @Stream
  // CHECKSTYLE:OFF too many parameters
  public Response getQuery(...)
```

How do I get resteasy to properly serve the data asynchrously, using the `SingleProvider` or otherwise.

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Get` method must return the `Single` explicitly or it doesn't work. (Can't use `Response` or `Object`). In my case, the `Single` contains the jaxb xml root element.

```
  @GET
  @Path(FdsnwsPaths.QUERY)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  @Stream
  public Single<FDSNStationXML> getQuery(...)
```

Then, to make things more complicated, in order to handle specific exception types and map them to specific response status codes, I have to create a custom `ExceptionMapper` which creates the `Response` object I used to be able to create directly in the method. (in resteasy-vertx, I found no documentation on how to do this, but in my case, I am creating my own `VertxRestEasyDeployment` object so I can register the class of the ExceptionMapper(s) like this:

```
VertxResteasyDeployment deployment = new VertxResteasyDeployment();
deployment.getActualProviderClasses().addAll(providerClasses);
```

For reference, this is all being done with:

- RestEasy 5.0.3.Final (including resteasy-rxjava2)
- RxJava 2.2.20
- Vertx 3.9.5